# Can't access Logitech c920 Webcam with opencv on Raspberry Pi 3 Stretch

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I can access and take a picture with the camera using  fswebcam. However, if I run the python code below I get: "Camera Not Online". I built opencv-3.3.1 and opencv_contrib-3.3.1 per [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/) and it works fine for my Raspberry Pi Camera Module just not for the webcam.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if cap.isOpened():
        print("Webcam online.")
    else :
        print("Camera Not Online")

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Going crazy. Any help greatly appreciated.